Segmentation fault when finishing Brotli compression
I use https://github.com/dropbox/rust-brotli to create my own compressor.
pub use brotli::CompressorWriter;
pub use brotli::DecompressorWriter;

impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for CompressorWriter<W> {
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut W {
        CompressorWriter::get_mut(self)
    }

    fn finish(mut self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
        self.flush()?;
        CompressorWriter::finish(self).map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream")
        })
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
} 

mod.rs
pub trait Coder<W>: io::Write {
    /// Acquires a mutable reference to the underlying writer
    ///
    /// Note that mutation of the writer may result in surprising results if
    /// this decoder is continued to be used.
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut W;

    fn finish(self) -> io::Result<W>;

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W>;
}

I create my encoder like
pub fn encoder<'a, W>(
    encoder_options: &CoderOptions,
    output: W,
) -> io::Result<Box<dyn Coder<W> + 'a>>
where
    W: io::Write + 'a,
{
        return Ok(BoxCoderDirect::boxed(brotli::CompressorWriter::new(
            output, 4096, 5, 22
        )));
    }

When starting encoding fonction on a folder, I get a segmentation fault on this line
CompressorWriter::finish(self).map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream")
        })

I use gdb to debug and found which line give issue.
I don't understand what is wrong :s
FYI, before I use https://github.com/bitemyapp/Brotli-rs and work as expected. (but latest commit was 4 years ago and latest release for 7 years ago)

There being no unsafe in your [mre] means the crate you use is unsound and you hit a bug (or you haven't posted a complete MRE), use something maintained instead. If you need help finding something you can ask on [softwarerecs.se].

https://github.com/dropbox/rust-brotli is maintained. It's why I use it.

Then you need to file that bug to them and wait for a fix / submit one yourself.

I fix issue myself

Great if you found a workaround please post an answer below.

I do
fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.flush()?;
        Ok(CompressorWriter::into_inner(self))
    }

To fix my issue
